# reading files in python using minimum lines of code

Tags: python

Is it possible to reduce this 4 lines code to 1 or 2 lines?

```
with open('tt.txt') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        if i != p.sub('', i):
            print (i)
```

Comment: `[i if i != p.sub("", i) else "" for i in open("tt.txt").readlines()]`

Comment: What is p here?

Comment: p = re.compile(r'something')

Comment: It's the proper number of lines, but those lines could easily be better.

Comment: `print("\n".join([i if i != p.sub("", i) else "" for i in open("tt.txt").readlines()]))` for the same output, I believe!

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("\n".join([i if i != p.sub("", i) else "%fix_me%" for i in open("tt.txt").readlines()]).replace("%fix_me%\n", "")
```

Updated to reflect comments on comprehension mistake..:

```
print("\n".join([i for i in open("tt.txt").readlines() if i != p.sub("", i)]))
```

Comment: Updated to remove empty lines

Comment: There! @superbrain, even dirtier, but very unlikely to grab something it's not supposed to.